# difference between property and public

Tags: objective-c

When declaring variables in an interface what is the difference between the two:

```
@interface thing:NSObject {
    int x;
    int y;
}
@property int x, y;
```

2:

```
@interface thing:NSObject {
    @public
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

Comment: What do you speculate may be the difference? What causes you to think that they are related? Have you read anything about the two that you don't understand and need explained? Have you done any experimentation or testing?

Comment: i just want a 5 word answer not extensive research and explanation. For someone that knows objective-c well im guessing would know this off the top of their head.

Comment: Yeah, we would. But the answer is more than five words.

Comment: Not too mention that it is very clearly documented....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@public is an access modifier that means you can access an attribute directly like this:

```
obj->someAttrib;
```

@property means that compiler should create accessor methods (if you're using @synthesize).

An important thing is that property doesn't necessarily match an attribute. You can create smth like this:

```
@property(readonly) int doSmth;
```

and then implement it:

```
-(int) doSmth {
   return 123+456;
}
```

However this is very rough and incomplete explanation (there is much more under properties). Read some articles/books about ObjC.

Comment: Whether or not something is declared as an `@property` has nothing to do with whether you can use the dot syntax.

Comment: @property really just declares two methods. If you declare `-someProperty` and `-setSomeProperty:` without using `@property`, you can still use dot syntax just fine. And trust me; bbum knows what he's talking about.

Comment: @BJ Homer - agree. my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

The property declaration, and the matching @synthesize statement, will create standard accessors for values named x and y.  the public declaration of your instance variables will allow any code in your app to access those values in your instance storage directly.

Comment: So set a variable as a `@property` will be heavier for the app than set as `@public` ? Because you said it will "_create standard accessors_" so I guess it will require more CPU, memory, etc… It isn't ?

Answer (score 0):

default is @protected so the only difference is if you wanted to access them directly, which is generally considered bad practice, but in the first example you could not do:

```
thing * aThing = [[thing alloc] init];
aThing->x = 5;
```

Edit: (as I got voted down by answering the actual question not the implied question.)

In Objective-C there are 3 visibility specifiers: `@public`; `@private`; and `@protected`.

The syntax only affects visibility of iVars, not methods, all methods are publicly visible.

the specifier works for all iVars following until it reaches another specifier;

`@public` allows direct access of ivars from outside of instances of the class or subclass.

`@protected` allows direct access of ivars from only in instances of the class or subclasses thereof.

`@private` allows direct access of ivars from inside of instances of the class, but not subclasses.

as for `@property` it is a language construct introduced with Objective-C 2.0 that allows you to use the `.` (dot) accessor for calling methods.

the default behavior is `@property int x` will reference 2 methods depending if you are using it as an left hand(setter) or right hand(getter) operator, the default getter will be `-(int)x;` and the default setter will be `-(void)setX:(int)x;`, @property doesn't in itself create those methods, but allows access to them.

the default behavior can be overridden with the following syntax `@property(getter=somethingOtherThanX,setter=somethingOtherThanSetX:)int x;`

Comment: If the OP doesn't know what `@public` means, do you think e will understand `@protected` without explanation?

Comment: You might also want to include two and a half words on the other part of the question, then. ;)

Comment: sorry i just started to learn the language after doing java so im used to that syntax and i was confused because oc uses the same ones but with different meanings.

Comment: -> is pointer * plus . accessor... all objective c objects are pointers, so it is a direct accessor to the object's iVar.

Comment: Although I am not responsible for the -1, allow me to point out (again :) that your answer does not address the whole question: the OP asked about `@public` _and_ `@property`.